# How to get the row before a row with certain value in SQL ? Say for error event for each user, i want to see the event just before it

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, row-number

I have three columns, `user_id`, `event_name` and `event_time`.

A user performs multiple events and the time for which is stored.

From the events, I want to get the event just before the LATEST 'failure' event (I am using BigQuery).

I have tried this:

```
WITH numberedlogtable AS
(
    SELECT 
        User_ID, Event_Name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User_ID ORDER BY Event_Time DESC) AS RN
    FROM 
        tablename
    WHERE
        date(Event_Time) BETWEEN '2024-02-12' AND '2024-02-24'
)
SELECT DISTINCT User_ID, Event_Name
FROM numberedlogtable
WHERE RN IN (SELECT RN+i 
             FROM numberedlogtable
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT -1 AS i 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 0 
                         UNION ALL 
                         SELECT 1) n
             WHERE Event_Name = 'fail_screen')
```

I am getting multiple rows for each user, and as I'm learning SQL, I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: Use `LAG` or `LEAD`, and keep the same `ORDER BY` as the row-number if possible, for better performance. `WHERE date(Event_Time)` is a bad idea, use date ranges instead `WHERE Event_Time >= '2024-02-12' AND Event_Time < '2024-02-24'`. Note that the `WHERE` is applied before the window functions.